# Updating dplyr in R gives "no package called ‘data_frame’" error

Tags: r, dplyr

I am having trouble updating from dplyr version 0.8.5 to 1.0.2 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. The error that I get is hard for me to understand.

I update using the following command: `update.packages(ask=FALSE,dependencies=TRUE)`, I am running R with root privileges.

`Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) :  there is no package called ‘data_frame’ ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘dplyr’`

What does `there is no package called ‘data_frame’` mean? I thought data_frame would be available since it is in the base package.

Comment: `data_frame` is not a base R thing, `data.frame` is. (The `_` vs `.` makes a difference here). `data_frame` used to be a function in `tibble`/`dplyr` but it's since been deprecated . It's unclear why R would think it's a package though and not a function as it really is. Is there more to the output? What R version are you running?

Comment: My version of R is 3.2.3, perhaps its time to update? And that is the end of the useful output

Comment: Oh yikes. That was released in back in December 2015. I'd say it's certainly time for an update, though technically dplyr seems to only require 3.2 or newer. It's still unclear to me where exactly that error message could be coming from.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out upgrading my base R version fixed the issue. I went from 3.2.3 to 3.6.3 and then I could get dplyr 1.0.2.